# Filter the strings which startswith (one or two) slashes in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell, filter, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to find out the strings which starts with one slash(/) and two slashes(//). For example, following is the array which have few strings:
Following is the code I'm trying:

```
$array = @("/website","//windows_service","/console_app","//windows","///IIS","test")
$arraysplit = $array.split(',');
Foreach ($string in $arraysplit)
{
    if ($string.StartsWith("/"))
    {
        Write-Host "$string has one slash."
    }
    elseif($string.StartsWith("//"))
    {
        Write-Host "$string has two slashes."
    }
    else
    {
        #I want to exit only when below conditions meet
        #1. if string doesnot have any slash or
        #2. if string has more than two slashes
        Write-Host "$string has more number of slashes or it doesnot have any slash. Exiting"
        Exit -1
    }
}
```

I dont want to write more `if` conditions to filter the things, but this is not working as expected. I think i should change the logic to achieve the requirement. Can someone please suggest me (I'm looking for dynamic method)

Comment: `if ($string -match '^/*') { write-host $matches[0].length slashes }`

Comment: __if__ you are guaranteed to only have _leading_ slashes, then `(($array[$i] -split "/").length) - 1` is the number of leading slashes.

Comment: I should note that this looks more like a homework problem than anything else...

Comment: @wOxxOm That reads like an answer.

Comment: For what it is worth I don't know why you have downvotes aside from the poor title. I am happy to see you try something.

Comment: `$array` is already an array after it is declared

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks a lot. it is working great. But how can I mark your solution as answer ?

Comment: @Matt Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($string -match '^/*') { write-host $matches[0].length slashes }
```

is the answer posted by @wOxxOm. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I would write an if-test that matches any lines that doesn't start with one or two slashes using regex. Try:

```
$array = @("/website","//windows_service","/console_app","//windows","///IIS","test")
Foreach ($string in $array)
{
    if ($string -notmatch '^\/{1,2}[^\/]')
    {
        Write-Host "$string has more number of slashes or it doesnot have any slash. Exiting"
        Exit -1
    }
}
```

Comment: I know it was in the question but I would remove the `$arraysplit` logic. `$array` is an array already.

Comment: No need to escape `/`.

Comment: Maybe not, but regex101 loves it (PHP engine) and it doesn't hurt. :-)

Comment: @FrodeF. it helps. Thank you.

Comment: Well, `\/` is less readable, also regex101 has a flavor option: you can switch it to golang.

Comment: Then use `^/{1,2}[^/]`. It really doesn't matter as they both work. However, both javascript and php will complain, so why not provide a solution that fits all three? Someone using one of the languages might find this post later looking for the regex.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

just inverse your test, because if a word start by // it start by /

```
$array = @("/website","//windows_service","/console_app","//windows","///IIS","test")
$arraysplit = $array.split(',');
Foreach ($string in $arraysplit)
{
    if ($string.StartsWith("//"))
    {
        Write-Host "$string has two slash."
    }
    elseif($string.StartsWith("/"))
    {
        Write-Host "$string has one slashes."
    }
    else
    {
        #I want to exit only when below conditions meet
        #1. if string doesnot have any slash or
        #2. if string has more than two slashes
        Write-Host "$string has more number of slashes or it doesnot have any slash. Exiting"
        Exit -1
    }
}
```